# Time keeps reverting to incorrect UTC and Local time on boot, however BIOS is always correct

Tags: time

My correct time is UTC -5.

I can modify by `sudo ntpdate ntp.uiuc.edu` and it fixes the time, but reverts to incorrect time again on next boot. Regardless of what I set time zone to, it does not persist beyond current session. I'm lost, I've tried all of the date/time modifiers that I know. Thank you.

```
┌──(charles㉿LA)-[~]
└─$ date
Thu Sep 15 12:39:09 PM CDT 2022 ***(THIS IS 5 HOURS EARLIER THAN THE CORRECT LOCAL TIME)***
                                                                                                       
┌──(charles㉿LA)-[~]
└─$ timedatectl
               Local time: Thu 2022-09-15 12:39:15 CDT ***(5 HOURS EARLIER THAN CORRECT LOCAL TIME)***
           Universal time: Thu 2022-09-15 17:39:15 UTC ***(THIS SHOULD BE +5 TO BE CORRECT UTC, WHAT IS SHOWN HERE NOW AS UTC IS ACTUALLY THE CORRECT LOCAL TIME)***
                 RTC time: Thu 2022-09-15 17:39:15
                Time zone: US/Central (CDT, -0500) ***(CORRECT TIME ZONE)***
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
                                                                                                       
┌──(charles㉿LA)-[~]
└─$ sudo ntpdate ntp.uiuc.edu
[sudo] password for charles:
ntpdig: socket error on transmission: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
ntpdig: socket error on transmission: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
ntpdig: socket error on transmission: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
{"time":"2022-09-15T17:41:24.7665-0500","offset":17990.543553,"precision":0.039600,"host":"ntp.uiuc.edu","ip":"130.126.24.44","stratum":2,"leap":"no-leap","adjusted":true}
CLOCK: time stepped by 17990.543553
                                                                                                       
┌──(charles㉿LA)-[~]
└─$ date
Thu Sep 15 05:41:31 PM CDT 2022 ***(NOW IT IS CORRECT)***
```

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/718996/system-time-is-incorrect-until-i-use-internet-but-hwclock-is-correct

Answer (score 0):

After boot, system date is set as per hardware clock. So, after setting software clock by ntpdate, you need to sync it with hardware clock using

> sudo hwclock --systohc

Comment: That is not what the info says for that command. It says the opposite of what you are saying.